# Unable to start Rails server on EC2 boot nginx+passenger. (Linux CentOs)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have successfully set up nginx+ passenger on my ec2 box (Amazon Linux)

I need to start the rails server each time the ec2 instance boots ( By boot I mean, `stop` and then `start`)

I can start the sever by going into the app directory and doing `passenger start -e p -p 80`

But I'm not able to start it every time it boots.

I tried to put it in `/etc/rc.local` which looks like:

```
cd /home/ec2-user/myapp
rvmsudo passenger start -e p -p 80
```

But that doesn't work. Even tried writing a bash script and putting it in `/etc/init.d/`. Did `chmod +x` on it. But still it doesn't work. If I run the script manually like `bash start_script.sh`. It works fine.

Also if I put something like `mkdir tempfolder` it works.

Why isn't the rails server not starting?

**nginx.conf**

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   /home/ec2-user/myapp/public;
            passenger_enabled on;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   /home/ec2-user/myapp/public;
        }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you browse to your server?

Comment: it works properly. the app is serving properly

Comment: So... everything is ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK when `nginx` starts, it takes care of the `passenger` which takes care of the `rails`.

`nginx` should start on machine startup. If it doesn't try running

```
sudo update-rc.d nginx defaults
```

On a more general note, not every `bash` script simply works under `init.d`. It needs to be an [an Init Script LSB](https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts)

I believe this is a template to help you create one (I've never tried it though - so it is on you...): https://gist.github.com/naholyr/4275302

Comment: I'm talking about how to start the rails server. ngix does start on boot.

Comment: passenger is the one which starts the rail server, and it is started by nginx. If that's not the case, there might be a problem in your `nginx.conf` - add it to your question.

Comment: Oh sorry. I mean passenger. But I don't think on system boot the application servers are started by default. one needs to start them manually, If I'm not wrong.

Comment: From personal experience, that is not needed. Again, if it doesn't work for you, it is probably a configuration issue.

Comment: Forget nginx+passenger. I wasn't even able to start webrick/unicorn server on system boot.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49178/discussion-between-uri-agassi-and-mrudult)